# Default header path of gcc when innstalled in other than /usr/local

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

I want to install the latest gcc on my Linux system to compile the C++11 code. Currently we are thinking of installing it on location other than the default like `/home/user1/newgcc`.

For that I will build it with --prefix=/home/user1/newgcc option. But AFAIK, the compiler looks for the header in the `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/include` etc. Since it will be installed in my local directory, how shall I force it look the headers in `/home/user1/newgcc/include` etc?

Will this path be hard coded while building the gcc with prefix option?

Comment: Yes, `--prefix` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the gcc/g++ configuration [options](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html), it seems that the `--prefix` option is  used to control the top-level installation directory of the build artifacts. If you want to specifiy a directory other than `/home/user1/newgcc/include`, you can use the `--with-local-prefix` option. In general though, `--prefix` parameter sensibly initialises all subsequent path parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should not install the compiler to a user local directory if there are multiple users on your box. If you do so you run later into problems when the dynamic linker try to get the libs from the users local path and other user have no access to this directory.

Typically additional software should installed somewhere in /opt of your system. We use /opt/gcc-version/... for this and we have a a lot of old compilers on our build boxes. While compiling your source the compiler knows where to find the appropriate headers.

BUT:

When you later run your progs on the system it could be possible that you have trouble finding the correct dynamic libraries. You have to add them to your ld.config system. Sometimes a file, sometimes a directory with a lot of sub folders. Simply look into your ld.config man page for this topic.